# Odoo search specific one2many field only in user defined filter

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to make a **user defined filter** to filter `res.partner` by `contract_ids` (`one2many`).

But I only want to filter by contracts that are currently with `state='open'`.

Example:

```
[[u'contract_ids', u'!=', False]]
```

But this only shows users that have a contract, not necessarily an open contract...
I tried this to no avail:

```
['&', [u'contract_ids', u'!=', False], [u'contract_ids.state', u'=', 'open']]
```

Any ideas?